# Mathematical presentation of a problem

Tags: constraints

The issue that I am dealing with now ends up with the solution of a second order equation. The solutions are the Z positions of a point in 3D. So, basically I have two points with the Z positions of $Z_i (i=1,2)$.

To choose between these two points I need to define the equation $|Z_i-C|$ where $C$ is a constant. The appropriate $Z_i$ is the one that minimizes this equation ($|Z_i-C|$).

Now I am wondering if there is anyway to mathematically represent this procedure in an equation-form. By equation-form I mean something like $Z= min ( ... |Z_i-C| ... $.

Thank you

Comment: I'm very sorry but I can't understand what you intend. Maybe you can add some more context. While you're at it you may want to use [MathJax](/help/notation) to typeset mathematical formulae correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just modified my question and tried to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the $\mathrm{arg\;min}$ operator:
$$Z = \mathop{\rm arg\;min}_{Z\in\{Z_1,Z_2\}} |Z-C|$$

Comment: perfect, thank you and sorry for this foolish question.

Comment: @NESHOM There's nothing foolish about asking for a notation :) This one is most common in optimization theory btw.

Comment: Is it also correct of I write something like this for example? $Z = \mathop{\rm arg\;min}_{i\in\{1,...,10\}} |_{ }^{C_j}\textrm{Z}_i-C|$

Comment: @NESHOM The $\mathrm{arg\;min}$ in this case would give you the index $i$. To fix this write
$$i_0 := \mathop{\rm arg\;min}_{i\in\{1,\ldots,10\}} |^{C_j}Z_i - C|\\Z := Z_{i_0}$$(or index the whole construct like $Z_{\ldots}$, but that's a mess^^)

Comment: So, if instead of two Z ($Z_1,Z_2$) there was 10 of them, how should we shorten it and not include all of the Z?

Comment: Is there any modified version of what you suggested originally for more than two Z?

Comment: @NESHOM You can use set-builder notation there:$$Z = \mathop{\rm arg\;min}_{\{Z_i : i=1..10\}} \ldots$$

Comment: Great, thank you very much :)